# What is the clash rate for md5?

Tags: security, hash, cryptography, md5, hash-collision

What's the probability for the clash for the md5 algorithm? I believe it is extremely low.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to hash about 2^64 values to get a single collision among them, on average, if you don't try to deliberately create collisions. Hash collisions are very similar to the [Birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

If you look at two arbitrary values, the collision probability is only 2<sup>-128</sup>.

The problem with md5 is that it's relatively easy to craft two different texts that hash to the same value. But this requires a deliberate attack, and doesn't happen accidentally. And even with a deliberate attack it's currently not feasible to get a plain text matching a given hash.

In short md5 is safe for non security purposes, but broken in many security applications.

Comment: 2^(n/2) as predicted by the birthday problem.

Comment: Due to this information, does it suitable to create documents ids for a system contains millions of documents based on their md5 hash of their respective content.? @CodesInChaos

Comment: @sємsєм I'd rather use SHA256, but MD5 shouldn't be a problem as long as the documents are created by a benign party.

Comment: I prefer md5 due to performance I think md5 is much quicker than SHA256, is not it? @CodesInChaos

Comment: @sємsєм It is faster, but even SHA-2 and SHA-3 can handle several hundred MB/s on a desktop CPU. If that's still not good enough, you can look at Skein or Blake2, which are almost as fast as MD5 while still being secure. | Alternatively if you can use a secret key, HMAC-MD5 is still relatively secure.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: @Albert "that's 1 clash every X files" You can't really say it like that, because the probability scales quadratically with the number of files.

Comment: Doesn't being attackable means that the algorithm is no longer perfectly random? Thus precluding "two arbitrary values, the collision probability is only 2-128"?

Answer (score 7):

It generates a 128-bit value.  The accidental clash rate should therefore be 2<sup>-64</sup> (because of the Birthday Paradox).

Comment: The collision probability because significant around 2^64 values, but the clash rate for two arbitrary values is only 2^-128.