# Using MD5 checksum to uniquely address a binary content in DB

Tags: hash, md5

I need to take binary  (images and pdf's) from one environment to another . 
These binaries are referenced in a main document mostly HTML Doc as Title and Version No: .
**The problem is that we have a versioning** ,So an HTML DOC might reead to  `img src=(Logo1 + Version 2)` . The Title is good for me , but the Version is system generated for the host system's use .

I need take the HTML Doc to another system - I can ofcourse insert the Logo assosiated - I don't want to just insert the image(or pdf) , if it is already available in the destination system . Can I use a combination of Title + MD5 Checksum to check if the destination system already has the same content possibly with a different Version No:. I think the chances of a collision is bare minmal with this approach ?  We have Md5's stored in our document manager system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chances for collisions depend on the number of documents you have to store, but should be sufficiently low.

But this assumes nobody actually tries to create collisions. MD5 is considered broken, so if somebody could benefit from causing collisions on your end he/she might be able to pull that of.

Therefore I'd recommend a more secure hash function. It shouldn't make much of a difference for your effort which one you use.

See also this question and answer: [What is the clash rate for md5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852668/what-is-the-clash-rate-for-md5)

Comment: Its relatively minor say in max in the order of thousand documents . Appreciate the link to clash rate of Md5 .