# Removing duplicates from table that are not set with a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with a `bit` column named `IsRetry`. I want to remove all the duplicate email addresses that are not set as `IsRetry`. If there are duplicates of the IsRetry I want to remove those too. I tried partitioning by `IsRetry`, but I am still ending up with emails that are set as `IsRetry` and not. The SQL below is removing the duplicates, but it is keeping one of each email. Meaning, one set as IsRetry and one not. Should I run a query to remove the initial duplicates then another to remove any duplicates that are not IsRetry or can I make this into one query?

```
CREATE TABLE Emails
(
    [EmailAddress] varchar(50)
    ,[Md5Hash] NVARCHAR(32)
    ,[IsRetry] bit
);

insert into Emails (EmailAddress,Md5Hash,IsRetry) 
    VALUES('email1@gmail.com',  '4d35f7e71ffa6246b55f14da99e18ede', 1)
insert into Emails (EmailAddress,Md5Hash,IsRetry) 
    VALUES('email1@gmail.com',  '4d35f7e71ffa6246b55f14da99e18ede', 0)
insert into Emails (EmailAddress,Md5Hash,IsRetry) 
    VALUES('someemail@testplace.com',   'c8e5b73cbe5438c62e9ca001929cb05d', 1)
insert into Emails (EmailAddress,Md5Hash,IsRetry) 
     VALUES('someemail@testplace.com',  'c8e5b73cbe5438c62e9ca001929cb05d', 0)
insert into Emails (EmailAddress,Md5Hash,IsRetry) 
    VALUES('someemail@testplace.com',   'c8e5b73cbe5438c62e9ca001929cb05d', 0)
insert into Emails (EmailAddress,Md5Hash,IsRetry) 
    VALUES('memeTest@hotmail.com',  'ddcb2ab8af5ff8c8040defebf471d5df', 1)
insert into Emails (EmailAddress,Md5Hash,IsRetry) 
    VALUES('memeTest@hotmail.com',  'ddcb2ab8af5ff8c8040defebf471d5df', 1)
insert into Emails (EmailAddress,Md5Hash,IsRetry) 
    VALUES('memeTest@hotmail.com',  'ddcb2ab8af5ff8c8040defebf471d5df', 0)
insert into Emails (EmailAddress,Md5Hash,IsRetry) 
    VALUES('memeTest@hotmail.com',  'ddcb2ab8af5ff8c8040defebf471d5df', 0)

;WITH cte 
AS(
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Md5Hash,IsRetry ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
            ,IsRetry
            ,EmailAddress
     FROM Emails 
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1

Select * from Emails
```

[Here is the fiddle for it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f068b/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to leave only one email.  If `IsRetry` is set, then you want that to be the one set.  If so, then you don't want to *partition* by `IsRetry`.  You want that in the in the `order by` clause:

```
with todelete as (
     select e.*,
            row_number() over (partition by EmailAddress
                               order by IsRetry desc ) as seqnum
     from Emails
    )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

I changed the partitioning to use `email`.  It is possible to have two different emails with the same MD5 hash code.

Comment: That is perfect! Just curious, what are the chances of a colliding MD5 hashed email? I know it is possible given the fixed length of MD5, but never gave much thought to collision. So, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @DDiVita . . . Okay, it is very, very unlikely to ever happen with random email addresses (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852668/what-is-the-clash-rate-for-md5), but there still seems little reason to use the hash code instead of the email address itself.